# ExtJS 5.1 bug workaround tabpanel scrolling

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I found the bug report and that it was resolved in 6.0.2 but I can't find a workaround. Does anyone know of a workaround for [EXTJS-16281](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?296225-Tab-Panel-Tabs-Scrolling-Issue-by-Mouse-Wheel)?

**Version:** 5.1.0

**Bug:** TabPanel does not horizontal scroll (switching active panels) with mousewheel.

**Notes:** Seems to work in Chrome 36 but not in FireFox 31.6

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on [this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305697-mousewheel-event-does-not-work-in-FF) after posting.

The original value of Ext.$eventNameMap.DOMMouseScroll is 'dommousescroll'

Setting Ext.$eventNameMap.DOMMouseScroll = 'DOMMouseScroll' resolved my issue

**Bug:** EXTJS-19223

**Fix Version** 6.0.2